# Insert multiple values in one column from a form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to insert the values with comma separate in same column database.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <div class="abc">
        <input type="text" name="year" class="pro_ip">
            <select name="duration">
                <option>Year</option>
                <option>Month</option>
            </select>
            <input type="text" name="rate" class="pro_inp">
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="textarea_pro_inp" placeholder="Leave your message..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="abc1">
        <input type="text" name="year" class="pro_inp"> 
        <select name="duration">
            <option>Year</option>
            <option>Month</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" name="rate" class="pro_inp">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="message" class="textarea_pro_inp" placeholder="Leave your message..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I have that type of code and I want to insert the field values in four columns but comma separated.

Answer (score 1):

Set all the element name as same name `inputname[]`

```
<form method="POST" action=""><div class="abc">
<input type="text" name="inputname[]" class="pro_inp">

<select name="inputname[]">
<option>Year</option><option>Month</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="inputname[]" class="pro_inp">

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="inputname[]" 
class="textarea_pro_inp" placeholder="Leave your message...">
    </textarea>
```

Use `implode`

```
$str=implode(",",$_POST['inputname']);
```

save value in table :-

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column) VALUES ('$str')
```